# How to draw anchor part of google map infowindow?

Tags: android, google-maps

I was able to customize infowindow by setting drawable as InfoWindowAdapter's view's background. But i don't have any idea how to draw anchor part of the infowindow.

This is what i did.

**InfoWindowAdapter**

```
  public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private PelicanApplication appState;
        public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter(Context context,Activity act)
        {
            this.context=context;
            appState = ((PelicanApplication)act.getApplication());
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
            return v;
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**InfoWindow View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_infowindow"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_pickup_address"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
        android:text="(1km, 5min)"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_info_to_get_sender"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_divider_width"
        android:background="@color/selector_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_divider2line_width" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_recipient_address"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
        android:text="(1km, 5min)"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_info_to_get_recipient"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_price"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
        android:text="(1km, 5min)"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_package_details"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_divider_width"
        android:background="@color/selector_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_divider2line_width" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_view_details"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="View Details"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_divider_width"
        android:background="@color/selector_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_divider2line_width" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_accept_delivery"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Accept this Delivery"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see i set **bg_infowindow** as the background.

**bg_infowindow.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_color" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/selector_color" />
    <corners

        android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

What i got so far

[image]

What i want(I marked the part i want to draw). In this screenshot anchor is on the right side of the infowindow. I want it on the bottom of infowindow

[image]

I don't want to set a image as the background

Comment: U can refer this for customization of infowindow.. http://androidhumanrobot.blogspot.in/2014/11/custom-info-window-in-google-map-android.html then customize it as per your requirement.